# How to use the paho mqtt library with a C++ ros node

Tags: c++, cmake, ros, paho, pahocpp

I just spend some time trying to figure out how to use the Paho Mqtt library in a C++ Rosnode and write this in case anybody has the same problem.

Comment: What was the **specific** error or issue you were running into? This is not really a question...

Answer (score 1):

Install the Paho library as described in the Github readme.

In the Cmakelists.txt of the Rosnode add:

```
find_package(PahoMqttCpp REQUIRED)

target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME}
  PahoMqttCpp::paho-mqttpp3
)
```

in the package.xml add:

```
  <depend>PahoMqtt</depend>
```

That should be everything to use it in your C++ code.

Comment: Can you provide a link to the README file you are referring to?